# While loops using less than provide errors

Tags: python, loops

I am making a Heads/Tails program, and I want the player to play for a seemingly infinite amount of time, but when I hit start it just makes me input H or T over and over. How do I make it move on, but still loop? (Sorry if this is a duplicate question. I looked but couldn't find an answer I was satisfied with)

Here is my code:

```
b_ht=['H', 'T']
streak=0
games=0
print('Press x to Quit')
g_ov = 'Game over. Total games: ' + str(games)

i=0
while i < 99999999999: p_ar=input('H/T')
b_ar=random.choice(b_ht)
if p_ar=='H' and b_ar=='H': print('Good job! It was heads!!')
if p_ar=='H' and b_ar=='H': streak=streak+1
if p_ar=='T' and b_ar=='T': print('Good job! It was tails!')
if p_ar=='T' and b_ar=='T': streak=streak+1
if p_ar=='H' and b_ar=='T': print('Sorry... It was tails...')
if p_ar=='H' and b_ar=='T': streak=0
if p_ar=='T' and b_ar=='H': print('Sorry... It was heads...')
if p_ar=='T' and b_ar=='H': streak=0
if p_ar=='x' or p_ar=='X': print (g_ov)
print('Current Streak: ' + str(streak))
```

Comment: Your while loop only repeats the part after the colon on same line. To repeat more, don't put anything after the colon and indent the following block you want to repeat.

Comment: Is that the *actual* indentation of your code? Are you aware that Python uses indentation to determine blocks?

Answer (score 0):

A really nice simple idea for a game with history. I've edited your code so that it works now:

```py
import random

b_ht=['H', 'T']
streak=0
games=0
print('Press x to Quit')
i=0
play = True
while play:
    p_ar=input('H/T\n')
    b_ar=random.choice(b_ht)
    if p_ar=='H' and b_ar=='H': 
        print('Good job! It was heads!!')
        streak=streak+1
    if p_ar=='T' and b_ar=='T': 
        print('Good job! It was tails!')
        streak=streak+1
    if p_ar=='H' and b_ar=='T': 
        print('Sorry... It was tails...')
        games += 1
        streak=0
    if p_ar=='T' and b_ar=='H': 
        print('Sorry... It was heads...')
        games += 1
        streak=0
    if p_ar=='x' or p_ar=='X': 
        g_ov = 'Game over. Total games: ' + str(games)
        print (g_ov)
        play = False
    print('Current Streak: ' + str(streak))
```

There are a few notes I'd like to make:

- a single `if` statement can have multiple commands run after it. You must format it with a new line and then the standard indentation for your file:

```
if condition:
    do something
    do something else
else:
    do something
```

- Be careful about the positioning of your print statements, e.g. the game over statement should be printed when `'x'` is pressed.
- We defined a new variable `play` that is set to `True` at the start but changes to `False` when `'x'` is pressed, and the game is over, causing the `while` loop to break